# Expandable textarea with max-height with css only

Tags: css, textarea, expandable

I wanted to ask, is it even possible to make expandable textarea with max-height (that should be 50% of parents height) with css only?
I was looking days for solution, but every time i find something it's with javascript (I already made one and it's working) or things like contenteditable which I don't like.
It should obviously shrink back when text is deleted.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Textarea doesn't support auto expanding by default.

Comment: You might also want to check the `rows` and `cols` attribute of textarea. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_rows.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Textarea doesn't support auto expanding by default. But you can do it super easy with js:

```html
<textarea name="text" oninput='this.style.height = "";this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px"'></textarea>
```